# Tableau - Finding Records that happened within X amount of time

Tags: tableau-api

I have some experience with Tableau as I have migrated into a Data Analyst position with not a ton of experience and am hitting a wall with if it is even possible to perform the calculation within Tableau.

The general base of my data would look like (Limiting it to the two fields we need)

1. Case #   |   Tech Dispatch Time (PST)  | Full Time (Y/N)
2. 2017-0001|   MM/DD/YYYY 16:34:21                  |      0
3. 2017-0002|   MM/DD/YYYY 20:43:00                  |      1
4. 2017-0003|   MM/DD/YYYY 22:00:05                  |      0

We are looking to see how often a dispatch happens within X amount of time to determine our efficiency in dispatching our teams.  If these were happening on the same record, a basic DATEDIFF and IF function would work, but I am at a loss on how to state that IF there is another dispatch in say 180 minutes, 1, else 0.

Is this something I will have to do outside of Tableau within say SQL or PowerPivot? Or is this a function that Tableau could calculate as well?

Thank you for your time and assistance with this matter,

Andy M.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parameter to define your 'x',
Then create a calculated field with below Formula(I called it time block)

```
//We need to add 0.5 to Roundup
ROUND((DATEDIFF('minute',[Tech Dispatch Time],NOW())/[x])+0.5,0)
```

Now you can use it in your viz
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Jose!  Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I tried this out and it doesn't seem to work and I have a couple questions.  Using the now() doesn't that create an issue when I am working with Records from 2016?  My goal is just to see for historical data and current data if there was another dispatch in those 180 minutes, and if so mark it with a binary marker that can be used to get how often two dispatches within this time frame happen to each other, and what hour do they occur.  Thank you again for your time!  Andy M.

Comment: Sorry, I miss read your question. I will take a look at it again when l am back from work

Comment: @MCMaster, No, it wont create any problem for 2016 data. It just classifies your data in to blocks of 180 minutes(assuming you set x at 180). NOW() is just a reference. If you just want the dispatches happened in last 180 minutes, Time Block '1'  will have that data and you can use an if condition to binary mark them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LOOKUP()` function. It allows you to find other rows' values relative to the current row.

```
DateDiff("minute", [Tech Dispatch Time (PST)], Lookup(MIN([Tech Dispatch Time (PST)]), -1))
```

The sample data you have in your question presents a problem though. The `Tech Dispatch Time (PST)` field only has the time portion. To accurately calculate time difference, you need a date with the time. Otherwise, you will end up with negative times if the two cases span across midnight.

Since this is a table calc, you'll also have to set the partitioning and addressing dimensions and sort order by editing the table calc to get the effect you want.

Comment: Hi Sam!  Thank you for taking time to reply.  First, it was my mistake completely, my time stamp does have the date as well, edited to show that.  Two small questions with this.  First  - when it searches for the next record, will it find the next row?  We work in medical dispatching and our records are not dated in order or dispatch, but order of time receipt/severity, so the next record might have dispatch 4 hours later, but a more severe one came in 5 records down and was dispatched 30 minutes after the original record.  Will this catch that? As well, running into some table calculation

Comment: Errors resulting in all null values following the setup, minus having to do Lookup(Attr()) as it says all fields must be an aggregate while using table functions.  Again, thank you Sam.  Andy M.

Comment: @A.McMaster, Alex Blakemore made some correction edits on the function I provided. See if his edit helps eliminate your errors.